# Assign anonymous injected method factory name of caller

Tags: javascript

I need the name function to be defined for use with another method further down so I need it to be dynamically named.

currently...

```
`use strict`;
const factory = () => () => {}

const method = factory();

method.name === undefined

&&
const factory = () => { const name = () => {}; return name }

const method = factory();

method.name === "name"
```

because...

```
`use strict`;
const factory = () => () => {}

factory() === () => {} // and () => {} is not a named method
```

But I want...

```
`use strict`;
const factory = () => () => {}

const method = factory();

method.name === "method"
```

this is extra description because stack overflow wants me to say more but I think that the problem is self-explanatory

Comment: Your question is not self-explanatory. Please explain what you're trying to do and what actually happens.

Comment: "*I think that the problem is self-explanatory*" kind of, except - why does it matter what the `name` property is?

Comment: Alright I added some more details, hope that helps. I'm trying to not over-complicate the question by over explaining.

Comment: You want a named function and use a lambda. Why?

Comment: because I need to use the name to index for it later in the flow

Comment: I don't think what you are trying is possible, and it sounds like an XY-problem.

Comment: "*because I need to use the name to index for it later in the flow*" Bingo! That's what I thought it was. *You should not rely on the function's name!*

Comment: `const method = factory(); method.name === "method"` suggests that I wanted it to by dynamically named.

Comment: To elaborate "isn't possible", i always mean apart from operating on code itself, where a lot is possible, but that's typically not in the cards.

Comment: WHAT is the actual problem you are trying to solve that you need o do this.

Comment: @ASDFGerte sure, it's not really practical and at this point I'm just interested in `something` that works even if that something is rediculous and I wouldn't use it in production, lol

Comment: 95% of the time people ask like questions like this and it is a flaw in their code and they think doing random stuff like this is the solution. It is like opening a window with a hammer. Yes it will work, but unlocking it to open it is a better solution. Sorry that I am trying to understand the core of the problem and maybe lead you to a better solution.

Comment: Please don't use the question area to use answers you got and then comment and elaborate on them. That is not how Stack Overflow is  supposed to work.

Comment: Okay, how should I share my alternative then? Can also just delete though, but I thought it might be useful

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question, but post it as a proper answer. Still, if in your answer you make use of older answers, you should add an attribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your arrow function a traditional `function`:

```
const factory = () => function method() {}
```

If the name is to be dynamic, then we have to deal with the fact that a function's name property is read-only. The function definition could happen in a dynamic way (but that involves parsing), or we could create a proxy:

```js
const factory = () => new Proxy(() => console.log("hello"), { 
    get(obj, prop) {
        return prop === "name" ? "method" : prop;
    }
});

const method = factory();

console.log(method.name);
method();
```

### Variable name

In comments you explained that the *dynamic* name should be determined by the variable name (i.e. `method`), but:

1. There can be many variables referring to the same function, while a function has only one name -- so that leads to an unresolvable paradox.
2. Variable names only exist at parse time, not at execution time.

Comment: I need it to be dynamically named

Comment: That was nowhere in your question. Proves that it was not that self explanatory?

Comment: Added more to my answer to cover that dynamic part.

Comment: I'm noticing that the only way to change the name is by changing the "method" string. But the ideal solution would be one that would return whatever the `method` variable is called. Is that possible that you know of?

Comment: So what determines the (desired) value of the name? A global variable?

Comment: just whatever the variable it will be saved to is; for example using your example.. `const foo = factory(); const bar = factory(); console.log(foo.name, bar.name);\\"foo bar"`

Comment: How would you imagine the following to behave: `let bar = foo;`. Now what will be the name? Realise that there is only *one* function object here... so it has *one* name.

Comment: the name in that case would be "foo", but isn't that just the behavior of JS?

Comment: Yes, but that contradicts a bit what you said... that it should have the name of the variable. But then you have `bar.name === 'foo'`...

Comment: so then what you're saying is it is not possible because if it were then the name variable wouldn't be guaranteed constant?

Comment: Indeed, in fact, variable names only exist at the moment of parsing, not at execution time. If you want names to exist at execution time, then you can think of *properties*, instead of *variables*.

Comment: @Alita "*the name variable wouldn't be guaranteed constant*" [Bingo!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66605672/assign-anonymous-injected-method-factory-name-of-caller#comment117743144_66605672)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by creating an object with the dynamic `name` prop and assigning the function to that prop:

```js
`use strict`;

const factory = s => (
    {[s]: () => {}}[s]
)

const method = factory('blah');
console.log(method.name)
```

Comment: I don't disagree that this can work. Indeed it does. However, I'm wary that OP's wanted result leads to extremely brittle code. The `name` might be altered for any reason. For example, in the future, somebody might decide to do `const method = memoize(factory("blah"))` and suddenly the code that does `if (f.name === "blah") { doSomething()}` doesn't work.

Comment: Also, if the name needs to be passed in, it's already not very dynamic. You might as well have `Object.defineProperty(method, "name", { value: "blah" })`.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work? You'd have to repeat the name, though, so not sure it totally gets what you're looking for

```
let factory = (name) => new Function(`return function ${name}() {}`)();
let method = factory("method");
method.name; // "method"
```

Answer (score 0):

Building off of @trincot's answer, what was initially proposed is not possible.

However, here's what I went with for a sufficient alternative:

```js
`use strict`;

// @trincot's answer
const renameFunction = (name, func) => new Proxy(func, { 
  get(obj, prop) {
    return prop === "name" ? name : prop;
  }
})

const identifyFunction = (obj) => {
  if (typeof obj === "object") {
    // because the object has the original defined as a property
    // we can pull the name back out
    const name = Object.keys(obj)[0];
    const func = obj[name];
    return renameFunction(name, func)
  }
  // if it's not an object then assume it's named and return
  return obj
}

const useFooName = (foo) => {
  let _foo = foo;
  
  // only need to identify if it's an object
  if (typeof _foo === "object") {
    _foo = identifyFunction(foo)
  }

  // using both the function and its name
  console.log(`${_foo.name} ${_foo()}`);
}

const factory = (func) => func;
const foo = factory(() => "bar");

useFooName(foo)     // bar
useFooName({ foo }) // foo bar
```

This can be used dynamically as well...

```js
`use strict`;

// @trincot's answer
const renameFunction = (name, func) => new Proxy(func, { 
  get(obj, prop) {
    return prop === "name" ? name : prop;
  }
})

const identifyFunction = (obj) => {
  if (typeof obj === "object") {
    // because the object has the original defined as a property
    // we can pull the name back out
    const name = Object.keys(obj)[0];
    const func = obj[name];
    return renameFunction(name, func)
  }
  // if it's not an object then assume it's named and return
  return obj
}

// let there be a function that accepts and function bar
// and uses bar's name; for whatever reason you don't want to
// change this method
const useBarName = (bar) => `${bar.name} ${bar()}`

// let there also be an arbitrary amount of functions using this
const traditionalWay = () => {
  const a = () => "b";
  const c = () => "d";
  const e = () => "f";

  console.log([a, c, e].map(useBarName).join(" ")); // a b c d e f ...
}

// but instead of hard-coding the functions it'd be easier
// to just build a factory that did it automatically
const brokenWay = () => {
  const factory = (letter) => () => letter;
  const a = factory("b");
  const c = factory("d");
  const e = factory("f");

  console.log([a, c, e].map(useBarName).join(" ")); // b d f ...
}

// so instead you can use the indentifyFunction to identify
// the anonymous methods
const newWay = () => {
  const factory = (letter) => () => letter;
  const a = factory("b");
  const c = factory("d");
  const e = factory("f");

  console.log([{a}, {c}, {e}].map(identifyFunction).map(useBarName).join(" ")); // a b c d e f ...
}

traditionalWay();
brokenWay();
newWay();
```